# Tracing jars from BOM

Tags: spring, gradle, byte-order-mark

Is there an easy way for me to trace a jar back to which BOM artifact it is from?
I need to upgrade org.dom4j:dom4j, but I need to figure out which of the artifact brings it in. Is there a way to print out all the transitive dependencies in Gradle? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on if you use gradle wrapper or not, `gradlew dependencies` or `gradle dependencies` should give you the dependency tree, but it doesnt show which BOM sets a specific version.

But it will show you if a dependency forces another dependency to chance its expected version.
I would recommend pipe it to a file to read easier (windows == `gradle dependencies > dependencies.txt`)